# Django SAAS projects

Tags: database, django, saas

I am almost done developing a Django project (with a few pluggable apps).

I want to offer this project as a SaaS (something like 37signals.com).

i.e: customer1.product1.com , customer2.product2.com etc

product1 could be the basecamp
product2 could be highrise 
and so on.

I want to know how the project should be structured for these products.

Should there be a single project under which all products will be an application.
                        ---- OR ----
Should I be making  different projects for all the products.

Also interms of database.. should all the products look into a single database or we should have seperate databases for each product.

I am looking out for the most efficient and scalable way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want the apps to interact in any way (e,g, share user accounts), they need to be on the same database. Until Alex Gaynor's [great work on multiple database support](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/branches/soc2009/multidb?rev=11074) gets merged into trunk, Django doesn't support multiple databases.

Along the same lines, [Django's sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) may be of interest to you. Without any more information about your intentions, it's difficult to give any better advice.

Comment: Update: the multi db support is now available in the trunk, and is in the 1.2 Beta release.

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleDatabaseSupport

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few big clients, giving each their own database and Django instance might make sense.  Especially if you need to do customisations for them.

For a SaaS app where there are potentially lots of clients with "create your own" setup and self-service admin, you probably want one database and add subdomain support in the Django app.

Here's some good tips and code on how we did it: [Handling Subdomains in Django](http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2008/12/12/handling-subdomains-in-django/).

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project claiming to handle a lot of the infrastructure for a basic 37Signals-like Saas site:  http://github.com/saas-kit/django-saas-kit